# Seeking library to do Spatial Network Analysis using QGIS

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, network-analysis

I am new doing network analysis out of R, I would like to know which is the best library to fulfill a spatial network analysis with Qgis?

I have been trying with Qnetwork, but I have problems by establishing the relations between areas.

Comment: what server or docker resources do you have access to?

Comment: GitHub may be a good one

Comment: well pgRouting in PostGIS via PostgreSQL database server is great, but OSRM on it's own server is very powerful as well. if you have pgRouting, there are tools that QGIS has to consume it, but everything i've seen requires either pgRouting or OSRM

Comment: Thanks! I have already taken a look at both, first I will try PostGIS, it seems to be quite straight forward.